# Putting lower bound and upper bounds on numpy.random.exponential

Tags: python, numpy, exponential

I want to extract samples from the exponential distribution with lambda =2 , however these must be bounded between 1 and 10.I know the usual syntax for creating samples in the exponential distribution however I do not know how to bound it .

Also I cannot use scipy.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
t = 0
t < 1 or t > 10:
    t = np.random.exponential(2)
```

That should do it